# Creating mobile different look than existing site?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

looking for a bit of advice more than anything.

I have a desktop version of a site here, that they now want to be a mobile version of.

charlesregionalcareers.org

I've built sites in responsive manners before, but the thing is that the layout they are desiring in the mobile version looks so much different than the desktop that it would make sense to just create a mobile only template of the page... is it possible to have it so that if someone visited that site in a mobile device, it would then bring up a mobile only page that's redirected from the desktop version?

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your best bet is to use css media queries.

If you use user agent based redirection, this may lower your sites rankings in google.

For example if every page redirects to your mobile sites homepage on mobiles, this will decrease your rankings on google.

Comment: I found a wordpress tool wptouch that still uses the url but does not change the desktop layout so this is the best route.  I'm all for media queries normally but it's just too much of a pain in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider a mobile ready CSS framework:

- [Foundation (Zurb)](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [Twitter Bootstrap (Twitter)](http://getbootstrap.com/)

These are the best ones I have ever used, you could google it btw :).

In both you could chose what to be visible on mobile and what not, and it all could be in you pages without redirection to a subdomain and etc. Check the documentation on both(which is pretty good) and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, typically you would check the http user agent (contains mobile info).  If the agent is mobile, you redirect from www.charlesregionalcareers.org to m.charlesregionalcareers.org

Comment: The redirection to m.domain.tld is not required